# ping AWS SNS service to validate connection in AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am writing a small component in a c# web-api, to send notifications to Amazon SNS. On different server environments (development, test, staging, production), my application connects to different SNS topics, and to different accounts on AWS. What i would like is some sort of "ping" to validate that i have a proper connection to AWS and SNS-topic when i have deployed my application (to avoid exceptions from the SDK if something goes wrong in the configuration/initialization of the AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient / SNS topic arn).

Is there some way to validate the state of the client and/or the topic in the C# SDK?

I have thought of implementing a publish of a bogus "ping-message" that listeners can just throw away - but i would like to avoid this if possible.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"?  What are your expected options of possible states the topic can be in?  Far as I know, the only states I'm aware of are "valid topic" and "invalid topic".

Comment: You are correct. Also i could(and would like to) validate/verify the credentials injected via. config at deploy time (that varies from environment to environment) By verify i mean, that the access key and secret key are correct (that amazon responds with `200 OK` and not with an authentication error)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make an request to AWS and return back the HttpStatusCode. I dont know SNS but i have worked with S3. If i were doing it i would do something like this.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string awsAccess = "";
        string awsSecret = "";
        string bucketName = "";

        AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(awsAccess, awsSecret, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

        var buckets = client.GetBucketLocation(bucketName);

        string httpResponse = buckets.HttpStatusCode.ToString();

        if (httpResponse == "OK")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HttpStatus: Good");
        }
        else Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Hope this helps